# How to code a conditional program in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I would like to run a program if a value of a certain cell change.

For example, if the value of cell E9 changes then run the following program:

```
Sub macrorepeatsolveNRTL()

Dim count As Long
count = 3
Do While count <= 203
    SolverOk SetCell:=Sheets("ParametersNRTL").Cells(count, 27), 
    MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=1, ByChange:=Sheets("ParametersNRTL").Cells(count, 12)
SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
count = count + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: re: *'... if a value of a certain cell change'* If it changes from typing a new value then use a Worksheet_Change to capture the event, if it changes from recalculation of a formula then use Worksheet_Calculate.

Comment: Can you help me write the if statement? I'm new to programming.

Comment: Actually, no... I cannot. Specifically due to the fact that you neglected to clarify the single most important fact that I alluded to in my previous comment. Seriously, I'm not here to play twenty questions.

Comment: thank you. I appreciate giving me your time.

Comment: And to clarify for anyone else, I want it to change from typing a new value.

Answer (score 2):

Put this into the code module of the worksheet that has the "E9" cell you are watching.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Range("E9").Address Then
        Call macrorepeatsolveNRTL
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT: Place in your worksheet module, not a standard module.** You can accomplish this task easily by right-clicking the worksheet tab in the spreadsheet, then click "View Code".

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim myTarget As Range
    Set myTarget = Range("E9")

    If Not Intersect(Target, myTarget) Is Nothing Then
        macrorepeatsolveNRTL
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it